# Use another website from an HTML file running locally

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

I am trying to load another website from a webpage I am running locally. While it does load, I can not seem to reference anything inside. I keep getting

```
Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "http://theWebsiteImAccessingWithTheIFrame.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "file", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
```

I get that this is a security feature, but there must be a way to reference the stuff inside if it is loading it anyway, no?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit:

I have created a map of the office I work in, using SVGs, with everyone's information(office location, their photo, extension, etc). We also just got a bunch of IP Phones that are managed and hosted by LightPath. On the webpage they have, it lets us manage our phones and even make them call others(using javascript but I have no idea how since their code is insanely complex).

My plan was that if a user clicked on someone's office, they could then have a button that would ask them to enter their number and pin to log in(how it works on the lightpath website), it would connect their 2 phones. I intended to use their number and pin to log in for them, and have the call connect that way, by just controlling the forms on lightpath's site, while it was in an iframe. This way, they wouldn't see Lightpath's site's clutter(because I could hide the iframe), and it would just get done. Essentially, it would happen as if they had gone to the website themselves and done it that way, except in a much more approachable format, and with less distractions.

LightPath does offer a "call me" feature which creates a dedicated button for calling a specific person, but it creates a token for them, and only that person has the ability to create it, not to mention I would have to enter each persons' unique token into the site, and run the risk of it failing should their extension get changed, or they leave the company. So I was hoping for something a little more dynamic.

Comment: Yes, you can do this via the Web Messaging API, which allows two windows on different domains to communicate with each other via message passing.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage for more info.  Both widows must opt-in, of course, by making appropriate use of the API.  You will need a set of conventions that both windows follow in order to effectively communicate as well.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work. I don't have control over the other page. But thank you though.

Comment: You have no control over the other window on a different domain, but want to access properties on this window?  No way to do this.  You are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature from the browsers.

You can't access iFrames which are not from the same origin.
So the file has to be local.

They have to be on the same server. In chrome you aren't allowed to access any other file in the `file://` protocol.

So to access remote files you may want to look into other ways of accessing it.
But either way, you need — at least in Google Chrome — to be on the `http://` protocol.

Comment: hmmm. Well I'm trying to perform tasks only that other website can perform. I have full access to that website from the web, but the page I am making needs to run locally as we don't have a web server, and it's just a map of our office. Do you have any suggestions? I've no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Do you have control over the other websites or are these 3rd parties where you have no control? If you have no control over them then this looks not so good. Another suggestion would be to use `Greasemoneky` then. It completely depends on your needs. Could you tell a little bit more about your situation

Comment: No control. I will edit my initial post to give some more detail(can't fit it here)